# Unable to create PHP snippets and templates with eclipse Luna

Tags: php, eclipse, code-snippets, eclipse-luna, eclipse-templates

I am using Eclipse Luna with WDT & PDT installed. I has seen [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqMxaETAMaA) on creating code snippets. But in my eclipse I cant see the menu or buttons to create new snippets. Do I need to install any specific plugins for this?
Screenshots attached below.

Snippets[image]
Templates [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you type templates in the quick access bar, select php templates, then click new? first 1 min of vid.  I have eclipse Mars.

Comment: i could get it from there. But it is not listed in the views like shown in the tutorial. Also the buttons for creating it is also missing, as u can see in the above screenshot.